# How does JavaScript Injection work?

Tags: javascript

I was watching a DefCon talk and the speaker was saying he was able to infect JavaScript cache files, once the user visited his website/server. From there he was able to load scripts from other sites and infect them for when the user visits later on. Does anyone know how this works?

Talk PDF: http://www.slideshare.net/chemai64/owning-bad-guys-and-mafia-with-javascript-botnets (See page 7)

Talk Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QT4YJn7oVI (See 32:45)

Comment: Sounds like it may possibly be persistent cross site scripting. A quick google search should help.

Comment: It might be helpful if you provided a reference to the talk.

Comment: @wireghoul He literally just downloaded the file with document.write('SomeUrl.js') and it was infected

Comment: I'm not sure what we can add. The pdf you linked explains it.

Comment: It doesn't work though. I've tried it.

Comment: And on top of that, it doesn't add up, how does just downloading the script inject your JS into it?

Comment: So they operate a Tor exit node/open proxy and simply rewriting javascript as it passes through, explained at 9:57 onwards in the talk. I'm not sure what the question is

Comment: @wireghoul Erm. No that's not what they're doing. They don't connect it to Tor at all. They're just hosting their own Proxy for users to connect to. I understand that part. I'm not understanding how they infect JavaScript cached files on the users machines.

Comment: They don't infect cached files, they set the expiry header on the infected file to forever so it gets cached for a very long time

Comment: @wireghoul But then they simply add the script for the site they want to be infected for the client, and it now contains their infection. So when the user visits the other site (EX: Facebook.com) the two lines of for connecting to the botnet are added.

Comment: Correct, the added js can modify the DOM and make somesite.com reference targetsite.com/somescript.js which will then get downloaded through the proxy (ie, also infected) and cached for a very long time so the next time the user visits targetsite.com the cached js calls home.